# Spring Boot 3.x With WebClient and ObservationWebClientCustomizer

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-webclient

This was a very useful [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3).
Although, I could follow it through to have a client and server application running with observation in place, I was further trying to match my actual use case with this application setup, which includes WebClient bean that is being instrumented but, comes back with empty or "None" uri values in the http_client metrics. And in order to tackle this scenario, what I had to do in the past was to use a webclient customizer that took the webclient.builder as an argument and customizes the bean to add http_client metrics and the URI showed up.
But, here when I try a similar approach with our ObservationWebCientCustomizer Object, it doesn't have any effect and the very @Autowire of the customizer object is making the http_client metrics go missing.
Upon removal of the @Autowired injections, the metrics come back but with an empty uri value.
This is especially for the WebClient bean variants and not for the RestTemplate bean.
Any thoughts or examples of the usage and ways to customize our metrics in Spring Boot 3.x would be really appreciated?
Questions:

1. Does Spring Boot 3 support observation for Webclient beans like it does for RestTemplate?
2. Any reason for choosing RestTemplate instead of WebClient in this example?
3. How do we customize or use the WebClient and RestTemplate Customizers? What are their uses?
4. Do we have to use ObservationHandlers on the Client app too in order to be able to observe the http client calls?

Thank you, in advance. This could help many other people I have seen facing a similar situation.

@Brian Clozel It would be great to hear your thoughts on this

Comment: WebClient observation is supported and you're only supposed to get "None" values for uri template tags if your usage of WebClient leverages expanded URIs instead of URI templates. Please update your question with a code snippet showing how WebClient is being used.